# PHP Undefined offset: -1, how can I skip the negative index?

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I already have a program in java which works fine. I tried writing the same one in php and got to some errors.
For example, in this code

```
for ($i=0; $i<64; $i++) {
    $r=$i/8; 
    $c=$i%8;
    $temp=1;
    for ($j=-1; $j<=1; $j+=2) {
        for ($k=-1; $k<=1; $k+=2) {
            while(" " == $chessBoard[$r+$temp*$j][$c+$temp*$k])
            {
                 //some other code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$chessBoard is a two dimensional array

```
$chessBoard= array
(
    array("r","k","b","q","a","b","k","r"),
    array("p","p","p","p","p","p","p","p"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P"),
    array("R","K","B","Q","A","B","K","R")
);
```

I know that the error happens when I'm trying to access $chessBoard[$r+$temp*$j][$c+$temp*$k] when for example $r is 0 and $j is -1, then I get 0+1*-1 which is -1, but I don't know how to get rid of this problem and still have the program to work properly. It's still not clear to me why I didn't have the same problem in java.

Answer (score 0):

Before the code

```
while(" " == $chessBoard[$r+$temp*$j][$c+$temp*$k])
{
    //some other code here
}
```

put in:

```
if($r+$temp*$j < 0 || $c+$temp*$k) continue;
```

This will go to the next iteration of the for-loop and will not run into any `indexoutofboundsexception`